# Add logging count to the amout of times a script is run

Tags: debugging, logging, applescript

I'm really stuck. I want to keep a log of how many times a script is run. My script is the following

```
set actionlist to {"action1","action2}
--select an action
set actionlist to choose from list actionlist with prompt "hello" default items {"action1"} with title "Actions"
if actionlist is {"action1"} then
    set thefile to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file of type {"mov"})
    tell application "Terminal"

        do script "DO SCRIPT HERE"
        activate
    end tell

if actionlist is {"action2"} then
    set thefile to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose file of type {"mp4"})
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "DO SCRIPT HERE"
        activate
    end tell
```

I want a script-log.txt that counts any time and actions were executed.  Something like this:

```
action1 = 14
action2 = 21
```

Is this possible?  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable in a few different ways, depending on what your intent is. Simplest would be to set up `properties` like so:

```
property action1 : 0
property action2 : 0
```

And then each time you do action 1 or action 2 increment the property:

```
set action1 to action1 + 1
--[...]
set action2 to action2 + 1
```

The interesting thing about AppleScript properties is that they are retained across each run of the script so that you can build a cumulative total over time. The caveats are that:

- if you edit and recompile the script, the properties are reset to their initial values (0, in this case)
- The property values can only be accessed within a script context, either by using `Display Dialog` within the script to show them in an alert, by loading the script from another script and reading them indirectly.

If you prefer to write data to a file, you can use handlers like the following:

*...The following is edited significantly per requests in comments...*

```
property tracking_file : POSIX path of (path to home folder from user domain) & "script-log.txt"
property boundary_text : "--- Log ---"
property colon_delim : " : "
property actions_list : {"action1", "action2", "action3"}

tell application "System Events"
    if not (exists file tracking_file) then my initialize()
end tell

set chosen_action to choose from list actions_list with prompt "hello" default items {"action1"} with title "Actions"
if chosen_action is not false then
    writeToFile(chosen_action as text)
end if

on writeToFile(chosen_action)
    set file_pointer to openFilePointer()
    set tally_text to read file_pointer until boundary_text

    set action_label to chosen_action & colon_delim
    set tally_offest to (offset of action_label in tally_text) + (length of action_label)
    set current_action_tally to (text tally_offest through (tally_offest + 3) of tally_text) as integer
    set new_action_tally to zeroPad(current_action_tally + 1)
    write new_action_tally to file_pointer starting at tally_offest for 3
    write action_label & short date string of (current date) & " " & time string of (current date) & return to file_pointer starting at (get eof file_pointer) + 1
    close access file_pointer
end writeToFile

on zeroPad(a_num)
    return text -3 through -1 of ("0000" & a_num as string)
end zeroPad

on initialize()
    set intital_text to ""
    repeat with this_item in actions_list
        set intital_text to intital_text & this_item & colon_delim & "000" & return
    end repeat
    set intital_text to intital_text & return & boundary_text & return
    set file_pointer to openFilePointer()
    write intital_text to file_pointer
    close access file_pointer
end initialize

on openFilePointer()
    try
        set file_pointer to open for access tracking_file with write permission
    on error err_str number err_num
        display alert "Error " & err_num & ": " & err_str
        close access tracking_file
        set file_pointer to open for access tracking_file with write permission
    end try
    return file_pointer
end openFilePointer
```

Comment: @andystumpf — Yes, the two demo lines are just proof of concept. To use this to tally, read the data from file, increment it, and then write it back out to the file.  I'll update the code above to demonstrate.

Comment: The second option is awesome.  Thank you!  I see it writes 22,14, but is there any way have it tally?  Like first time I run action1 it would say
action1 : 1
action2 : 0

then if I ran action1 again
action1 : 2
action2 : 0

Comment: :hattip: this is awesome.  Now I'm wondering if there is a way to make a list and time stamp?  Am I pressing my luck? Something like 
`action1 01-01-2020  13:00
action1 01-05-2020  01:02
action2 01-06-2020  05:32`

Comment: That's easy enough, at least if you don't need the tally read back into the script.  delete the line that says `set eof of fp to 0`, and change the 3rd line of `writeToFile` so it reads: `write "action1 : " & short date string of (current date) & " " & time string of (current date) & return to fp` That should rule you a running list of when each action was performed.

Comment: Thanks Ted!  I'm getting this error `Can’t get item 2 of {"action1 : 1/30/20 11:00:36 AM"}.` . Looks like it doesn't like `last word`

Comment: When I run the script.  This is in the Result
`error "Can’t get item 2 of {\"ac\"}." number -1728 from item 2 of {"ac"}`

Comment: This is what I edited
`on writeToFile(val1, val2)
 set fp to open for access trackingfile with write permission
 write "action1 : " & short date string of (current date) & " " & time string of (current date) & return to fp
 close access fp
end writeToFile

on readFromFile()
 set fp to open for access trackingfile
 set log_lines to read fp using delimiter return
 close access fp
 return {last word of item 1 of log_lines, last word of item 2 of log_lines}
end readFromFile`

Comment: I *think* what went wrong is that you called the `readFromFile` handler, which expects the data written to the file to be formatted a particular way. We changed the way we wrote data to the file without updating how we read it back.

Comment: You've got shifting goal-post going on right now, which is confusing things. If you think for a minute and then spell out precisely what you want to write to the file, and what (if anything) you want to read from the file, then I'll do another revision to make that happen.

Comment: strange... I copied and pasted the script above and haven't edited anything

Comment: Yes, but are you calling the `readFromFile` handler from some other part of the script?

Comment: Sorry... With the possibilities of timestamping it made me broaden the project.  This is a screenshot of the desired result of the logging.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0nktp91mspj3el/script-log_txt_and_debugging_-_add_logging_count_to_the_amout_of_times_a_script_is_run_-_stack_overflow_and_tally-script.png?dl=0

Comment: I want to regroup with you on this Ted and give you the info you are looking for.  I appreciate your help and patience.  I'm a total noobie.  Let me know if there is additional info you need.  Thank you!

Comment: Andy, sorry: life intervened today. Give me till tomorrow afternoon; I see what you want from the link you posted, and I know how to implement it, I just need a chance to get to it.

Comment: I just took a another stab at it and nothing is working.  Any ideas @ted ?

Comment: OK, changed the code fairly significantly, and edited it into my answer.  This depends pretty heavily on the structure of the log file, so make sure you delete the old script-log.txt before you run this. The script will create a new file with the structure it wants.

Comment: Forgot to add... It will adjust itself to as many actions as you want to include, but if you change the number of actions, you have to delete the script-log.txt file and start over.

Comment: I tried running it and I'm getting a couple errors `Error -49: File file Macintosh HD:Users:user:script-log.txt is already open` . (Which is strange because its not open) Then it highlights this line `close access tracking_file` (5th line from the bottom) Should this script work on it's own?

Comment: Sometimes if you run into errors Script Editor gets confused about whether the file is open or closed. Quitting Script Editor and reopening it should solve that.

Comment: I closed script editor and re-opened and I am getting `End of file error.` and highlights `read file_pointer until boundary_text`.  I have deleted the `script-log.txt` and the script then creates a blank `script-log.txt`

Comment: I don't know what to tell you; I copied the script from my post back into script editor and it works perfectly. All I can suggest is the following: (1) Quit Script Editor. (2) Delete script-log.txt. (3) Empty the trash. (4) Open Script Editor. (5) Open a new Script Window. (6) Paste the code in the new window and try again.

Comment: WORKED!  Emptying the trash did it.  Thank you Ted for all the time you put into this and the back and forth.  I really appreciate it!